# Since we went vs since we have been

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Sentence transformation from a PET sample paper:

> We haven't been to the theatre for a long time.
>
> It's a long time since we ........ to the theatre.

My solution: went

Textbook solution: have been

Are they both correct?

Comment: What do you mean "both correct"? They're both grammatical sentences that mean more or less the same thing. But when you do a sentence transformation, aren't you supposed to use the same verb if you can?

Comment: @PeterShor in the instructions they only say ".. complete the second sentence so that it means the same as the first. Use no more than three words." :)

Comment: Poorly set question. You need a *been* to use either. Ngrams returns some examples using "s a long time since" as a the search string, but they are almost all from characters speaking in dialect. Others occur in foreign translations. I didn't find a single "straight" example. "It's [been] a long time since we [have been/went] to the theater.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are idiomatic.

The other obvious choice, *were*, does not work because it does not license the preposition *to*; it would have to be *since we were **at** the theater*.

I agree with Peter Shor that usually in questions like these, one should make the modification minimal. Therefore, a solution that uses the same base verb, *have been*, should be preferred.

One could frame this question more generally and ask whether *It's a long time since* favors the preterite or the present perfect for the verb that follows it. One could also ask whether it makes a difference if one uses *it's **been** a long time since*.

I've searched for both "it's a long time since" and "it's been a long time since" at the Corpus of Contemporary American English [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and the British National Corpus [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), and on google books. In brief, *it's a long time since* is followed by the preterite much more frequently than by the present perfect. As far as *it's **been** a long time since,* it is still the case that the preterite is more common, but not as decisively as when *been* is missing.

Here is a sampling of all four types of constructions (all the examples are from COCA):

*It's a long time since I **noticed**, she said, smiling.*                [no *been*, preterite]
*It's a long time since you'**ve been hurt**.*                     [no *been*, present perfect] 
*It's **been** a long time since I **tasted** venison.*                     [with *been*, preterite]
*It's **been** a long time since I'**ve had** a dog.*          [with *been*, present perfect]

Finally, here is a summary of the results from COCA and BNC. The 'total' column shows the total number of times the phrase to the left if the results appears in the corpus. The column 'pret.' is the number of times the phrase is followed by a verb in the preterite, and 'pres. perf.' shows the analogous number for the present perfect.

total     pret.    pres. perf.
*it's a long time since*:          COCA    16         8         4
                                              BNC      27       17          7

total     pret.    pres. perf.
*it's been a long time since*:  COCA    219         48         41 (out of first 100)
                                              BNC         5            3          2