# Examples where a verb licenses different prepositions depending on its tense

Tags: prepositions, tenses

In the course of answering [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274583/since-we-went-vs-since-we-have-been/521056#521056), I've noticed that there are constructions where the verb ***be*** licenses different (non-temporal) prepositions depending on its tense:

[1]   i  a.  *We've been **to** the movies.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=krqW3HNt-osC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA30&dq=%22we've%20been%20to%20the%20movies%22&pg=PA30#v=onepage&q=%22we've%20been%20to%20the%20movies%22&f=false)           b.  *<sup>?</sup>We've been **at** the movies.*
       ii  a.  **We were **to** the movies.*                           b.   *We were **at** the movies.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=eXWbAgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA23&dq=%22we%20were%20at%20the%20movies%22&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=%22we%20were%20at%20the%20movies%22&f=false)

We see that in this case, the present perfect licenses *to*, while the preterite does not; on the other hand, the preterite licenses *at*, while the construction present perfect + *at* is of somewhat marginal acceptability (to my ear, at least). These findings are confirmed if we search the Corpus of Contemporary American English [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/): there are 15 hits for *been **to** the movies*, but just one for *been **at** the movies*. In contrast, there are 11 hits for *were **at** the movies*, and none for *were **to** the movies*.

It seems that the verb ***be,*** depending on whether it is in the present perect or in the preterite, licenses different prepositions in these constructions.

Are there any other cases where the licensing of a (non-temporal) preposition similarly depends on the tense of the verb?

Answer (score 1):

"We've been to the movies" is an example of the special structure "to have been to" which is used to mean (more or less) "to have gone to." It seems similar to the use in Spanish of *fui* etc., the same past tense forms as the "to be" verb, for the past tense of *ir* "to go".

This is a very exceptional case, and I'm not sure that I would describe it as a case where the licensing of a preposition is conditioned by the tense of the verb.

I'm not sure whether my objection is relevant to your question, but I would instead describe the entire "have been (locative PP)" construction as restricted to the perfect tense, just as the "used to" construction found in "I used to eat there on Sundays" is restricted to the past tense.

I can't think of another example like it. "Have got" behaves fairly differently from the non-perfect verb "get", but I can't think of ways that is related to prepositional phrases.

Comment: Yes, I’m sure your comment is on the right track. You could add evidence like, (1) *We went at the movies, (2) we went to the movies (i.e. distribution like been to), (3) We have been present at the movies, (4) *We have been present to the movies (i.e. distribution like were at). The meaning is directional vs. locative, so it’s not just tense that changes in this case.